# Map and Apply a function on a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list like this:

```
{{1,2}, {4,2}, {6,4} ... }
```

I want to replace every second number with a function of that number. For e.g.

```
{{1, Log[2]}, {4,Log[2]}, {6,Log[4]} ...}
```

It is ok if the actual number is evaluated e.g. `{1, .301}` for the first one. I am trying to do this with a combination of `Apply`, `Map` and `ReplacePart` but am having no luck.

I do not understand how to do `@@` in cases where the nested list is supplied as an argument to the function.

Comment: Why not `{#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]]} & /@ { {1,2}, {4,2}, {6,4}}` ?

Comment: what do you mean...? and how do you use #, & and the /@ operator? I assume the last one is the Map operator, but I admit to not knowing how it works except that it will do f[element] for every element in a list where f is a function

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580113/using-all-in-mapat-in-mathematica/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a function as :

```
myF[alist_, f_] := Map[{#[[1]], f[#[[2]]]} &, alist]

myF[{{1, 2}, {4, 2}, {6, 4}}, Log]

(* {{1, Log[2]}, {4, Log[2]}, {6, Log[4]}} *)
```

Or you can generalize to :

```
myF2[alist_, f_] := Map[{f[[1]][#[[1]]], f[[2]][#[[2]]]} &, alist]

myF2[alist, {# &, Log}]
myF2[alist, {Sin, Log}]

(* {{1, Log[2]}, {4, Log[2]}, {6, Log[4]}} *)
(* {{Sin[1], Log[2]}, {Sin[4], Log[2]}, {Sin[6], Log[4]}} *)
```

Comment: thanks, this is really comprehensive.. the only problem is, can you explain how "f_", "#", "&" are to be used, and I assume *( and *) represent the output?

Comment: @user997301 I would suggest toe read the very nice tutorial from leonid! Evrything is explained there very well. http://mathprogramming-intro.org/

Comment: is it possible to do this in a one-liner?

Answer (score 15):

**`MapAt` and deeply nested lists generalization**

Another way to do this:

```
MapAt[Log, #, 2] & /@ {{1,2}, {4,2}, {6,4}}
```

> {{1, Log[2]}, {4, Log[2]}, {6, Log[4]}}

Which is useful if we target a specific element inside every element of a deeply nested list:

```
data = Table[{k, {k, {{k}}}}, {k, 2, 5}]
```

> {{2, {2, {{2}}}}, {3, {3, {{3}}}}, {4, {4, {{4}}}}, {5, {5, {{5}}}}}

```
MapAt[Log, #, {2, 2}] & /@ data
```

> {{2,{2,{{Log[2]}}}}, {3,{3,{{Log[3]}}}}, {4,{4,{{Log[4]}}}}, {5,{5,{{Log[5]}}}}}

Comment: how do you do log arguments though, ex. Log[1,2]

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf `MapAt[Log[b, #] &, #, {2, 2}] & /@ data`

Answer (score 14):

Since you seem to be relatively new to Mathematica, and unfamiliar with all its special syntax (`/@`, `@@@` etc), I would normally recommend Artes' second answer:

```
{#1, Log[#2]} & @@@ {{1, 2}, {4, 2}, {6, 4}}
```

Which can also be written

```
Apply[{#1, Log[#2]} &, testdata, {1}]
```

where `testdata = {{1, 2}, {4, 2}, {6, 4}}`

Some alternative ways of getting the same answer include:

```
MapThread[{#1, Log[#2]} &, Transpose@testdata]
```

and (I think this one is quite cool)

```
Inner[#1[#2] &, {# &, Log[#] &}, Transpose@testdata, List]
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `ReplaceAll` i.e.

```
{{1, 2}, {4, 2}, {6, 4}} /. {a_, b_} -> {a, Log[b]}
```

> ```
> {{1, Log[2]}, {4, Log[2]}, {6, Log[4]}}
> ```

or

```
{#1, Log[#2]} & @@@ {{1, 2}, {4, 2}, {6, 4}}
```

i.e. `Apply` the function `{#1, Log[#2]} &` on the first level of the expression.

Comment: I believe your second answer works, but not the first one.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf The first method works too, but if applied to singular cases it may yield unexpected results. In this case `a` is replaced by `{1,c}` and `b` by `{2,d}`. In general you have to be careful using pattern matching and if you cannot exclude cases when it fails or not sure how to use it better work with `Apply`.

Comment: My first comment concerned : `{{1, c}, {2, d}} /. {a_, b_} -> {a, Log[b]}` as an example when it fails to get what you'd like.

Comment: @Artes That problem can be solved using `Replace` with a level specification of {1}. I remember being mildly surprised when I figured out that `Replace` was good for something.

Comment: @Pillsy Thanks for a good hint.  I see other ways of dealing with patterns here but I find discussing them is out of the scope of this question since there have been given many nice solutions so far.

Answer (score 9):

when f is listable, use `Set` and `Part`:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {4, 2}, {6, 4}};
a[[All, 2]] = Log@a[[All, 2]];
a
```

Answer (score 5):

[`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) was updated some versions ago (V10? but not documented until [V11.1](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v11.1/ref/MapAt.html)) to handle this use-case.  An example similar to this may be found in the documentation:

```
MapAt[Log, {{1, 2}, {4, 2}, {6, 4}}, {All, 2}]
(*  {{1, Log[2]}, {4, Log[2]}, {6, Log[4]}}  *)
```

Answer (score 4):

From my answer in the thread that Leonid linked:

```
partReplace[dat_, func_, spec__] :=
  Module[{a = dat},
    a[[spec]] = func @ a[[spec]];
    a
  ]

partReplace[{{1, 2}, {4, 2}, {6, 4}}, Log, All, 2]
```

> ```
> {{1, Log[2]}, {4, Log[2]}, {6, Log[4]}}
> ```

Though this fails on version 7, ruebenko's answer is IMHO the most elegant for recent versions:

```
partReplace2[dat_, func_, spec__] := ReplacePart[data, {spec} -> func @ data[[spec]] ]
```

These both assume that `func` is `Listable`.

Comment: ReplacePart didn't work on the recent version (12.0)

Answer (score 3):

> Be careful, some method is really slow. :)
> The fastest one is always the "vectorization one".

[image]

Comment: Adding the code used to generate the table would greatly improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

My explanation of `# &`, `#2 &`, `## &`, `##2 &` can be found in my *Mathematica* tips and tricks pages as part of [the section discussing `Function`](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_A-K_34.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation of b.gatessucks's generalization:

```
Map[Composition[Through, {Composition[f1, First], Composition[f2, Last]}],
    {{1, 2}, {4, 2}, {6, 4}}]
   {{f1[1], f2[2]}, {f1[4], f2[2]}, {f1[6], f2[4]}}
```

For OP's particular example:

```
Map[Composition[Through, {Composition[Identity, First], Composition[Log, Last]}],
    {{1, 2}, {4, 2}, {6, 4}}]
   {{1, Log[2]}, {4, Log[2]}, {6, Log[4]}}
```