# Map w/ multiple arguments

Tags: functions, map

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use Map for a function with two arguments?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8147/how-do-i-use-map-for-a-function-with-two-arguments)

If I have a function:

```
F[x_,y_,z_]:=x*y*z
```

and I want to call it with several different x values using `Map` (and y and z fixed), is there a way to do that with a one-liner?

That is, for these x values

```
xVals = {1,2,3,4}
```

I want to somehow get:

```
{F[1,10,100], F[2,10,100], F[3,10,100],F[4,10,100]}
```

If I can do it with Map, it would be great, because I have many cores and want to speed this up with the parallelized Map.

Comment: You may use map with a pure function, `f[#,10,100]&/@ xvals`.  (I renamed your function to lowercase to keep with conventions.)

Comment: +1 Thanks! Is there a way to do it in a grid (i.e. vary xvals and yvals)?

Comment: I want to essentially do a nested for loop to return a nested list:  { forall yvals {forall xvals f[xval, yval,100]} }

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is a duplicate but I cannot find it.  Anyone?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard this one? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8147/8 or maybe this one: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4019/8

Comment: @Verbeia the first one is probably what I was thinking of; do you agree with closing?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes, in this case. Don't delete, though: the answers are good

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You may use map with a pure function:

```
f[#,10,100]& /@ xVals
```

> ```
> {f[1, 10, 100], f[2, 10, 100], f[3, 10, 100], f[4, 10, 100]}
> ```

Table will also work:

```
Table[f[x, 10, 100], {x, xVals}]
```

> ```
> {f[1, 10, 100], f[2, 10, 100], f[3, 10, 100], f[4, 10, 100]}
> ```

Multiple iterator form:

```
Table[f[x, y, 100], {x, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {y, {5, 6, 7, 8}}]
```

Comment: +1 I can also use parallel table to get an 8x speedup!

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Wizard, for the edits.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Outer` to get a nested output list :

```
Outer[f[#1, #2, 100] &, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}]
(* {{500, 600, 700, 800}, {1000, 1200, 1400, 1600}, 
   {1500, 1800, 2100, 2400}, {2000, 2400, 2800, 3200}} *)
```

However I'm not sure you can take advantage of `Parallelize`.

Answer (score 8):

```
F[x_, y_, z_] := x*y*z;
xVals = {1, 2, 3, 4};
yVals = {5, 6, 7, 8};
```

You could use thread for this:

```
Thread[d[xVals, yVals, 100]]
(* yields *)
{d[1, 5, 100], d[2, 6, 100], d[3, 7, 100], d[4, 8, 100]}
```

Comment: Does not work well with tensors, but MapThread does!