# How to evaluate multivariable functions at (multiple) specific points?

Tags: evaluation

How can one quickly evaluate a multivariate function like $z = 4x+5y$ at specific points (e.g. $P1 = (7.5, 0)$, $P2 = (3,9)$, $P3 = (32/3, 4/3)$ and $P4 = (10,0)$).

Specifically, I'd like to be able to view all values at the same time.

For a single variable function, I normally use a table such as:

`Table[(x^3-x^2-x-1), {x, 0, 16, 1.6}]`

(except here I am interested in listing discrete points)

Comment: quickly?  `4 #1 + 5 #2 & @@@ {{7.5,0}, {3,9}, {32/3, 4/3}, {10,0}}`

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the redirect to the other question. Two points of clarification i) is there room within this SE to ask about syntax appropriate for wolframalpha.com, specifically? ii) the other question does look thoroughly answered; however, the language of the question is very different and so the question does not show up in searches with google or on this site, nor even as a suggested "related question" when composing; is there room for a subtitle to the question that might increase its visibility (in hopes of saving everyone time)?

Comment: To be honest, I wasn't sure which question to mark this as a duplicate of, this is a question that comes up a lot, and I had been using mathematica for years before I started using `Map` and `Apply`.  When I searched I found [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8147/9490), [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27718/9490), and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11803/9490), and the one I linked to.  You can definitely edit the questions' title to make them better for future users.  As a new user, your edits are then vetted by others on the site for approval.

Comment: Thanks Jason - I'm coming at this more from the math side of thing, (but there is a rule against posting Wolframalpha / Mathematica Qs on the math SE) and so never would have known to use "Map" in my search - I'll consider making an edit to one of the titles once I have more experience on this SE.