# Dealing with nested lists

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, code-review

This question is strongly related to:

[Map and Apply a function on a nested list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4019/map-and-apply-a-function-on-a-nested-list)

I am in a bit of a rut in terms of my MMA skills and looking to improve my coding. I've realized that rather than taking advantage of all of capabilities of MMA, I've stuck to a few constructs that are easy coming from a procedural background such as using Table to replicate While-Do functionality.

I often have to deal with nested lists:

```
 n1 = 3; n2 = 6; n3 = 5; (*example*)

 list1 = Table[Table[RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, n1], {i, 1, n2, 1}], {j, 1, n3, 1}];
 list2 = Table[Table[RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, n1], {i, 1, n2, 1}], {j, 1, n3, 1}];
 list3 = Table[Table[RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, n1], {i, 1, n2, 1}], {j, 1, n3, 1}];
 list = {list1, list2, list3};
```

I typically have to apply some set of functions to the nested list as follows:

```
values1 = Table[Min@list1[[i]][[All, #]] & /@ Range[n1], {i, 1, n3}];
values2 = Table[Max@list2[[i]][[All, #]] & /@ Range[n1], {i, 1, n3}];
values3 = Table[StandardDeviation@list3[[i]][[All, #]] & /@ Range[n1], {i, 1, n3}];
values = {values1, values2, values3};
```

And plot the results:

```
Grid[{{ListLinePlot[Transpose@values1, PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotMarkers -> "x"]
, ListLinePlot[Transpose@values2, PlotStyle -> {Green}, PlotMarkers -> "y"]
, ListLinePlot[Transpose@values3, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, PlotMarkers -> "z"]}}]
```

**Question**: How would you rewrite **ALL** of the above code (including the list generation and plotting) in a functional style (without using Table) so that it is efficient and expandable?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Made one more edit on value generation....

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  However, I just noticed that in your update you used a different function (`StandardDeviation`) for `values3`; is that important?

Comment: MrW: thanks for that… yes, I need to apply Min/Max and StDev to list1 thru 3...

Comment: Okay, I'll address that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List generation can be done with this:

```
list = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {3, 5, 6, 3}];
```

The `values` list can be calculated without inputting specific dimensions; only depth is needed.  I write a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) to handle one expression, then [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) it onto `list` at *levelspec* `{2}`:

```
values = Map[Min /@ Transpose[#] &, list, {2}];
```

***Edit***: Or following your updated question, with a separate function for each sublist:

```
values =
  MapThread[
    Map[#2, Transpose /@ #, {2}] &,
    {list, {Min, Max, StandardDeviation}}
  ];
```

Plotting can be done by writing one function, then passing it arguments using [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html):

```
MapThread[
  ListLinePlot[Transpose @ #, PlotStyle -> #2, PlotMarkers -> #3] &,
  {values, {Red, Green, Blue}, {"x", "y", "z"}}
] // List // Grid
```

[image]