How to batch add vertex letters A, B, and C to each triangle？
How to batch add vertex letters A, B, and C to each triangle？
I tried the following code myself, but was unable to successfully add it
labels = {Text[Style[A, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #1, {2, 0}], 
  Text[Style[B, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #2, {-2, 0}], 
  Text[Style[C, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #3, {2, -1}]}

triangles = {{{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {16, 75}}, {{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {8, 
    7}}, {{-2, -7}, {3, 18}, {8, 17}}, {{2, 9}, {8, 17}, {15, 
    0}}, {{-2, 10}, {8, 17}, {15, 10}}, {{10, -7}, {8, 17}, {16, 
    5}}, {{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {6, 7}}}
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[#], 
    labels}] & /@ triangles


（-1）After asking 248 undeleted questions, you still learn nothing about defining function or basic list manipulation via /@, @@, etc.

If you can label one triangle and output a graphic using a function (say f) then f/@triangles //Show should be able to do the job. Can you write this function yourself?

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4019/map-and-apply-a-function-on-a-nested-list

Table[{Graphics[{FaceForm[Blue], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[t],
Text[Style[A, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], t[[1]], {2, 0}],
Text[Style[B, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], t[[2]], {-2, 0}],
Text[Style[C, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], t[[3]], {2, -1}]}]}, {t,
triangles}]

The main problem is that the arguments are localized. Therefore, the "#" in labels are not the same as those in "Graphics". To fix this, declare "labels" as a function:
labels = {Text[Style[A, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #1, {2, 0}], 
  Text[Style[B, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #2, {-2, 0}], 
  Text[Style[C, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #3, {2, -1}]}&

Then you need MapApply (@@@). Further, in "Polygon" and "labels", "#" means only the first argument. "##" means all arguments. With these changes:
labels = {Text[Style[A, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #1, {2, 0}], 
    Text[Style[B, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #2, {-2, 0}], 
    Text[Style[C, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #3, {2, -1}]} &;

triangles = {{{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {16, 75}}, {{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {8, 
     7}}, {{-2, -7}, {3, 18}, {8, 17}}, {{2, 9}, {8, 17}, {15, 
     0}}, {{-2, 10}, {8, 17}, {15, 10}}, {{10, -7}, {8, 17}, {16, 
     5}}, {{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {6, 7}}};
Graphics[{FaceForm[Blue], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[{##}], 
    labels[##]}] & @@@ triangles



Thank you for your help. It seems that the usage rules of this grammar/@, @ @, @ @ @ require a lot of effort to understand

Yes, it is confusing at first. It need some exrecise to master it.
