Transform List into Sublists with Curly Braces Around First Two Elements
Given a list list, how can it be transformed so that every three elements selected from left to right form a sublist, with the first two elements of each sublist enclosed in curly braces? The result should be list1.
list = {a, b, c, a, b, d, a, b, e, a, b, f, a, b, g}

list1 = {{{a, b}, c}, {{a, b}, d}, {{a, b}, e}, {{a, b}, f}, {{a, b}, 
   g}}

I attempted this approach, but it didn't yield the correct results.
list = {a, b, c, a, b, d, a, b, e, a, b, f, a, b, g};
list1 = Apply[{{#1, #2}, #3} &, Partition[list, 3]]


Simply use MapApply instead of Apply

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/302244/how-to-batch-add-vertex-letters-a-b-and-c-to-each-triangle#comment742787_302244 （-1）

SequenceSplit[list, {a_, b_, c_} :> {{a, b}, c}]

(* {{{a, b}, c}, {{a, b}, d}, {{a, b}, e}, {{a, b}, f}, {{a, b}, g}} *)

Or
MapApply[{{#1, #2}, #3} &]@Partition[list, 3]

 (* {{{a, b}, c}, {{a, b}, d}, {{a, b}, e}, {{a, b}, f}, {{a, b}, g}} *)

Or
MapThread[{{#1, #2}, #3} &, Transpose@Partition[list, 3]]


(* {{{a, b}, c}, {{a, b}, d}, {{a, b}, e}, {{a, b}, f}, {{a, b}, g}} *)

In addition, using the undocumented (but very useful) fifth argument of Padding
Partition[list, 3, 3, 1, {}, {{#1, #2}, #3} &]

(* {{{a, b}, c}, {{a, b}, d}, {{a, b}, e}, {{a, b}, f}, {{a, b}, g}} *) 

Just for fun
Using Map to replace the Head List in the partitioned list with a 'pure' function:
Map[Replace[List :> ({{#1, #2}, #3} &)], 
    Partition[list, 3], {2}, Heads -> True]

(* {{a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, b, e}, {a, b, f}, {a, b, g}} *)

A similar approach using MapAt
MapAt[Replace[List :> ({{#1, #2}, #3} &)], 
    Partition[list, 3], {All, 0}]


This works:
Partition[list, 3] /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {{x, y}, z}

(*{{{a,b},c},{{a,b},d},{{a,b},e},{{a,b},f},{{a,b},g}}*)

Edit:
The comment from @march makes a very important point. The case in which the length of list partitions into 3 means that ReplaceAll ( /. ) applies the rule successfully to the top level, which is not what we want. The use of Replace with a specified levelspec eliminates this ambiguity.
list = {a, b, c, a, b, d, a, b, e};

Partition[list, 3] /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {{x, y}, z}

(*{{{a,b,c},{a,b,d}},{a,b,e}}*)

(*This is not what was intended*)

Replace[Partition[list, 3], {x_, y_, z_} -> {{x, y}, z}, 1]

(*{{{a,b},c},{{a,b},d},{{a,b},e}}*)

(*This is what was intended*)

Partition[list, 3]

(*{{a,b,c},{a,b,d},{a,b,e}}*)

(*In the 2nd list the partitioned list matched the rule at the top \
{0} level so we don't get what we want *)


In this situation, it's safer to use Replace as opposed to ReplaceAll so that you can replace at the right level. That is, do Replace[Partition[list, 3], {x_, y_, z_} -> {{x, y}, z}, 1] instead. (Consider what happens for list = {a, b, c, a, b, d, a, b, e}.)

Thank you, @march. I think you make an important point.  I have edited my answer inspired by your comment.

For a very succinct elucidation of this point, see this post by @Szabolcs

list = {a, b, c, a, b, d, a, b, e, a, b, f, a, b, g};

SequenceCases[list, {a_, b_, c_} :> {{a, b}, c}]
SequenceReplace[list, {a_, b_, c_} :> {{a, b}, c}]


{{{a, b}, c}, {{a, b}, d}, {{a, b}, e}, {{a, b}, f}, {{a, b}, g}}


The reader can add another element to the list to see the difference in outputs between the two commands.

ArrayReshape[list, {Length@list/3, 3}] /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {{a, b}, c}


BlockMap[{{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, #[[3]]} &, list, 3]

Update inspired by @ydd:
BlockMap[Comap[{Most, Last}], list, 3]

Comap is new in version 14 and is marked as experimental

{Most[#], Last[#]} & /@ Partition[list, 3]

